# Flexigrid redraw existing instance

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

How to redraw existing flexigrid with new columns and data?
On page i already have one instance of flexigrid with data, how to redraw with new data when for example i click on some link?

Comment: I am partialy succeed. Like this: $("#flexi").remove();
$("#mainPanel").append("<table id=\"flexi\" ></table>"); But this but another flexi below first one...

Comment: anything :) some hint :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply

```
$("#flexi, .flexigrid").remove();
```